# Post cXML invoice to SAP Ariba Cloud Integration Gateway

Tags: sap-ariba

We have a supplier account on Ariba network & want to post cxml invoices to Sap Ariba Cloud integration gateway to send it to our buyers in Ariba Network. We are using HTTPS transport type.

1. In the below screenshot while creating Ariba cloud Integration project, Is it possible to skip entering URL "Connect CIG to trading Partner" section as we do not want any files to be delivered to us & directly post the cxml invoices to URL mentioned in "Connect Trading Partner to CIG" from our ERP. 
   In short, Our requirement is only to send Invoice from our ERP (non-SAP) through CIG to our buyers in Ariba network. We want to post invoices from our ERP (Non-Sap) to CIG directly without any Web server setup or middle ware. 
   Please let me know how this can be achieved. 
   [image]
2. Also when we test cxml invoice through postman by posting it to Ariba URL, We get “**Acknowledged**” status from Ariba as highlighted in below screenshot. 
   But there is no confirmation if the invoice is sent to buyer neither any notification message in our ariba outbox. 
   Have mentioned Buyer ANID in cxml invoice while post to Ariba url & buyer is from our customer list, not sure how to check further process & why there is no notification if the invoice is received by buyer. 
   [image]

Comment: As you say,  Ariba always send 'Acknowledged' and status 201 even if the post was not added to Ariba, I was told by SAP that this is a limitation of the CIG cXML solution